# Audit Plug-in for MYSQL 5.7.24 error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, audit

I have tried installing `MariaDB` audit plugin for `MySQL 5.7.24`.
I have downloaded the '`server_audit.so`' from  `MariaDB-10.3.11` and I think it is compatible with `MySQL 5.7.24`.
But I have encountered this error while running command

> INSTALL PLUGIN server_audit SONAME 'server_audit';
>
> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library
>   '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/server_audit' (errno: 2
>   /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/server_audit: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory)

thanks for any help

Comment: Do you mean MySQL 5.7.24?

Comment: yes, I mean MySQL 5.7.24

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/` the directory where you placed the `server_audit.so` file? Is the file readable to the `mysql` user?

Comment: yes, it's the path where server_audit.so is. and I guaranteed 775 privilege  to the file

Comment: I tried another plugin and I found the same error. I think you are right. MYSQL cannot see the plugin files. But I have no idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSTALL PLUGIN server_audit SONAME 'server_audit.so';
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/install-plugin.html), the SONAME should include the extension - '.so' in this case.